# How to get data from multiple databases in laravel 4.2 with same query in FLUENT or PDO?

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-4

```
$db1 = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name1,$db_username,$db_pass);

$db2 = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name2,$db_username,$db_pass);

$db1->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$db2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM table1 ";
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM table2 ";

$stmt1 = $db1->query($query1);  
$stmt2 = $db2->query($query2);

$results = array_merge($stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC), $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

return $results;
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer? If it's a question, pls highlight your error / output and expected output

Comment: There is no need to create new PDO connection because you can use one connection  for  multiple databases. for example `SELECT * FROM db1_name.db1_table_name` & `SELECT * FROM db2_name.db2_table_name`